# Clear an input after an ajax call

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I have the following jsf code for a primefaces input, which is being populated by a bar code scanner. After each scan I need to do something in the bean clear the input and refocus on it for the next scan. So far the bean works fine but the clear is not and I haven't started refocusing yet. Any Ideas?

```
<p:inputText id="testInput" value="#{barcodeHelper.barcodeData}"  onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13){onchange(); return false;}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{barcodeHelper.barListener()}" update="testInput" process="@this"  event="change"/>
            </p:inputText>
```

and the listener does this

```
public void barListener(){

    if(barcodeData.length() == 13){
        ean = barcodeData;
        //Will do more 
    }
    //other bar code Lengths will be dealt with maybe a switch is better
    //clear the data just read  
    barcodeData = null;
}
```

I get to the listener fine but unfortunately the `update="testInput"` does not work. What am I missing here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the ajax response body?  Use Firebug/Chrome to see it.

Comment: Just trying to get my head round Firebug as I have never used it before. I have viewed lots of useful data with it and can see the response function but don't seem to be able to see what the response is. Should I be setting the response in my java bean?

Comment: Firebug.. wow what a work of genius. I have found that the response is empty. Is this the problem?

Comment: @BalusC I have tried a few more things and have found that update="outText" to another element works fine ` <h:outputText id="outText" value="#{barcodeHelper.ean}"/><h:outputText  value=""/>` So can primefaces AJAX just not update its calling element in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post a bit more information--hop into the source and look at the rendering. You'll see something (my guess) like:

```
  <input id="j_1231:testInput" />
```

Depending on the setup you may need to explicitly path your update to the component in this case (again, a wild guess) :formId:componentId or :subviewId:formId:componentId. If your path is off this should be a quick fix.

--per Balus's comment

If the bean is registering an action you can use the Primefaces callback to fire a Javascript method. 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/callbackParams.jsf

Comment: The `<p:ajax>` is inside the same naming container as `<p:inputText>`, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: I have tried both these approaches Danial but to no avail. Considering BalusCs' answer above I think that the update is not getting called because of the state of the response. However when I tried using the oncomplete to call a javascript I was getting to the function but document.getElementById("myform:testInput).value = "" did not work either as I assumed (maybe wrongly) that the beans value was taking presidents. Its all very confusing.